# Flutter: TextFormField rebuilding dialog when tapped

Tags: flutter

I've got a simple dialog in my app to create a user profile.
It has an Image you can change and a TextFormField for entering the name.
But when I tap on the TextFormField, it rebuilds the dialog and resets the image variable. How can i fix this?

Here's the basic code (I get the issue with this code as well):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'dart:io';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Issue demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => MyDialog());
          },
          child: Text('show dialog'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  File image;
  String name;

  MyDialog({this.image, this.name});

  @override
  _MyDialogState createState() => _MyDialogState();
}

class _MyDialogState extends State<MyDialog> {
  final _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SimpleDialog(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
          title: Text('new person'),
        ),
        FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
          child: FlatButton(
            shape: CircleBorder(),
            child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage:
                    (widget.image != null) ? FileImage(widget.image) : null,
                child: (widget.image == null) ? Icon(Icons.person) : null),
            onPressed: () async {
              File newImage =
                  await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
              if (newImage != null) {
                imageCache.clear();
                setState(() {
                  widget.image = newImage;
                });
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: TextFormField(
              initialValue: widget.name,
              maxLines: 1,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              autofocus: false,
              onSaved: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  widget.name = value;
                  print(value);
                });
              },
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity),
                hintText: 'Name',
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Cancel'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
                child: Text('Save'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I've solved it now! My answer is below, though I have no idea why it solved the problem! :)

Comment: I just had the same issue, but the actual issue was somewhere higher in the hierarchy. For me it was a FutureBuilder that got recreated, but it probably could have been anything else

Comment: Which dialog are you using, can you share some codes?

Comment: Did you find the reason of solution?

Comment: No, I'm afraid. I solved the problem by accident!

Answer (score 2):

It's ok! I've solved it!!!!!

I simply moved the image variable to _MyDialogState and now it works!!!!
Can anyone tell me why it works??

```dart
class MyDialog extends StatefulWidget {

  File image;
  String name;

  MyDialog({this.image, this.name});

  @override
  _MyDialogState createState() => _MyDialogState();
}

class _MyDialogState extends State<MyDialog> {
  final _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String name;
  File image;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    image = widget.image;
    name = widget.name;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SimpleDialog(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
          title: Text('new person'),
        ),
        FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
          child: FlatButton(
            shape: CircleBorder(),
            child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage:
                    (image != null) ? FileImage(image) : null,
                child: (image == null) ? Icon(Icons.person) : null),
            onPressed: () async {
              File newImage =
                  await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
              if (newImage != null) {
                imageCache.clear();
                setState(() {
                  image = newImage;
                });
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: TextFormField(
              initialValue: name,
              maxLines: 1,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              autofocus: false,
              onSaved: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  name = value;
                  print(value);
                });
              },
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity),
                hintText: 'Name',
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Cancel'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
                child: Text('Save'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```